# THREE.js How to save a scene before refresh and load it once the page is done with refresh?

Tags: three.js

I have a web application where the users can add objects to the scene, move it around, change the rotation etc. But, I have a drop down which decides the unit system to be followed on the whole page for various parameters. The drop down, on change should go through a page refresh. This causes the whole scene to be reset. Is there any way to save the scene and then reload it to the previous state in three js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A beautiful example of what you are trying to achieve is the [three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) itself.You can find its source on [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/editor).

What it does it that it stores the editor's state in (i.e configuration,   `camera` and `scene` objects) into the `local storage` and `indexedDB` (you can live with only one also) and then when the page is initialized it checks if scene's `state` is set there in `indexedDB`, it loads it from there.

You might have to do some reading of the code itself but I'll explain the main logic here.

---

## 1. Loading the scene from local storage when the page loads

You can find that in `index.html` when there is this piece of code

```
  editor.storage.init( function () {
    editor.storage.get( function ( state ) {
        if ( state !== undefined ) {
            editor.fromJSON( state );
        }
        var selected = editor.config.getKey( 'selected' );
        if ( selected !== undefined ) {
            editor.selectByUuid( selected );
        }
    } );
```

So this checks that if there is data in the state it goes to `fromJSON`  function in `/js/Editor.js` which basically sets the `camera` and `scene` etc. to whatever was stored in `indexedDB` .See the exact code is

```
   fromJSON: function ( json ) {

        var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

        // backwards

        if ( json.scene === undefined ) {

            var scene = loader.parse( json );

            this.setScene( scene );

            return;

        }

        // TODO: Clean this up somehow

        var camera = loader.parse( json.camera );

        this.camera.position.copy( camera.position );
        this.camera.rotation.copy( camera.rotation );
        this.camera.aspect = camera.aspect;
        this.camera.near = camera.near;
        this.camera.far = camera.far;

        this.setScene( loader.parse( json.scene ) );
        this.scripts = json.scripts;

    }
```

To check how its loaded from the local storage/IndexedDB exactly you can check `Config.js` and `Storage.js` files located in the JS folder itself.

---

## 2nd Storing the data into IndexedDB periodically

Again in `index.html`  you can find the following code and updates the model in the `IndexedDB` this behavior can be triggered on an event or on a timeout or even manually by calling this piece of code `editor.storage.set( editor.toJSON() );`.

```
var saveState = function ( scene ) {
    if ( editor.config.getKey( 'autosave' ) === false ) {
        return;
    }
    clearTimeout( timeout );
    timeout = setTimeout( function () {
        editor.signals.savingStarted.dispatch();
        timeout = setTimeout( function () {
            editor.storage.set( editor.toJSON() );
            editor.signals.savingFinished.dispatch();
        }, 100 );
    }, 1000 );
};
```

Hoping you can make use of this example to achieve your target.

Comment: Brilliant example I love it it solved my problem